# perl script to delete lines from file

Tags: perl

I have a file that I want to read it and for each 'word' found to delete the next 2 lines including the line with the 'word'.
 the structure of the file is somekind line this:

```
1
2
3
word
321
3213
412
word
132
1231
```

this is what I have until now:

```
open FILE, "$localDir\\x.txt" or die $!;
@fileLines = <FILE>;
close FILE;

$output = 'y.txt';
open my $outfile, '>', $output or die "Can't write to $output: $!";

for ($i = 0; $i < scalar(@fileLines); $i++) {
       next if ($fileLines[$i] =~ /'word/);
         print $outfile $_ ;


}
```

thanks

Comment: you could just use vi and type :%s/^word.*\n.*\n.*\n//g or you could use this in a multiline regex to replace.

Comment: `grep -v -a2 "word"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The excellent [`Tie::File`](http://metacpan.org/module/Tie::File) module often seems to be forgotten. It is ideal for this sort of thing

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy qw/ copy /;
use Tie::File;

my $local_dir = '.';

copy "$local_dir/x.txt", 'y.txt';
tie my @file, 'Tie::File', 'y.txt';

for ( my $i = 0; $i < @file; ) {
  if ( $file[$i] eq 'word' ) {
    splice @file, $i, 3;
  }
  else {
    ++$i;
  }
}
```

#### output

```
1
2
3
412
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#iterate one line at a time. 
while ( <DATA> ) {
    #if we hit the delimiter, read and discard two more line. 
    if ( m/word/ ) { <DATA>; <DATA> ; }  
    #otherwise print it. 
    else { print; };
}

__DATA__
1
2
3
word
321
3213
412
word
132
1231
```

Which gives:

```
1
2
3
412
```